# How would I do this in a unix system?

Tags: linux, unix

I need to locate all of the file system objects below the /sbin directory that include a period (.) somewhere in the object’s name, but not objects that begin with a leading period.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your /sbin folder

Find *.txt file but ignore hidden .txt file such as .vimrc or .data.txt file:

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname "*.txt" ! -iname ".*" \)
```

The -type f option forces to only search files and not directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /sbin -name '*.*' | grep -v '/\.'
```

Can add `-type f` if only interested in files.