# How to print out all non-hidden files recursively in a dir using lpr

Tags: printing, find, pipe, lpr

`find . -type f | grep -v '/\.'` lists out all non-hidden files in the current dir recursively.

*Example of this command given the following file tree*

```
.
├── css
│   ├── base.css
│   └── main.css
├── img
├── index.html
└── js
    └── app.js

$ find . -type f | grep -v '/\.'

./index.html
./css/main.css
./css/base.css
./js/app.js
```

But how do I print all these listed files using `lpr`?
I tried `find . -type f | grep -v '/\.'|lpr` but this only prints this list instead of printing each file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lpr` prints out, what is sent to it via STDIN. So you need to invoke `lpr` for each file found by find:

```
find . -type f ! -name ".*" -print0 | xargs -0 lpr
```

- `-type f` searches for files
- `!` is a logical not, hence `! -name ".*"` will omit hidden files (with some help from https://superuser.com/a/101012/195224)
- `-print0` separates the individual filesnames with `\0` so that this will also work with file names with white spaces in it.
- `xargs` finally executes `lpr` with the list of filesnames it receives (`-0` again tells that `\0` is used as a delimiter).

This command will list only non-dot**files**, but also those in dot**dirs**.

If you also want to [exclude dotdirs](https://superuser.com/a/442340/195224), extend the `find` command to

```
find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*"
```

And finally, as some versions of `lpr` [have obviously a problem with empty files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73482/33390), omit these also:

```
find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*" ! -empty
```

---

As a sidenote: To get a nicer layout of your printout (includes file name) you should consider to replace `lpr` by `a2ps`.

Comment: The command `find . -type f ! -name ".*" -print0 | xargs -0 lpr` fails, I get `lpr: No file in print request.`.
And using this command without the `lpr` part lists out dotfiles as well so it doesn't seem to be the right command.

Comment: @Bentley4: The command I posted works here as intended with bash, tcsh and zsh. What's stange about your edited question: You are using `-type d` but find lists files not directories. Are you using GNU Linux?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I got that command from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916588/how-do-i-filter-dotfiles-out-recursively-using-find-in-bash) btw. Apparently it works for those other pple as well.

Comment: @Bentley4: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. `-type d` lists only directories for me...

Comment: Oh, I forgot I adapted that command. I'm such a dummy sometimes, sorry! You just need to replace d with f so you get this: `find . -type f | grep -v '/\.'`.

Comment: @Bentley4: Ok, that makes sense now. Back to my command. Are you sure `find . -type f ! -name ".*"` lists dotfiles? What it does is to list non-dotfiles in dotdirectories. But obviously you want to omit dotdirs, too. That's my fault, although it's not explicitely stated in the question it should be clear from the `grep -v` part... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Indeed, I meant also to omit dot directories. Sorry for not being clear enough on this.

Comment: @Bentley4: Hope, it works now.

Comment: `find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*"` lists all non-hidden files and directories just like you said. However `find . -type f ! -regex ".*/\..*" ! -name ".*" -print0 | xargs -0 lpr` still doesn't print and returns `lpr: No file in print request.`

Comment: @Bentley4: Can you please try, if `lpr` accepts more than one file? E.g. `lpr file1 file2`. This (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73469/33390) hints that it can also have to do something with _empty_ files...

Comment: It does accept multiple files.

Comment: @Bentley4: Ok, my last try (edited answer), to omit also empty files, as they seem to make troubles on some systems.

Comment: Nice catch on the empty files! Thanks so much. I'll take a look at `a2ps` since the output is quite ugly.

Answer (score 1):

With just the `find` command, use its `-exec` option:

`find . -type f ! -name ".*" -exec lpr '{}' \;`

which passes every matching file name to lpr (the `'{}'` is expanded to the each file name in turn).

Comment: This returns `find: missing argument to `-exec'`.

Comment: `\n` should read `\;`

Answer (score 1):

`lpr` can take multiple files, so

```
lpr ./*
```

...will print all files in the current directory. For recursiveness, if you have bash 4+, you can use

```
shopt -s globstar
lpr ./**
```

If sending directories to `lpr` causes problems, you can always use a for loop with a test (the second, recursive one requires globstar to be set):

```
for f in ./*; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && lpr "$f"; done
for f in ./**; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && lpr "$f"; done
```